# SNMP Mib. Are the "qualified" descriptors used in practice

Tags: snmp

According standard **RFC 2578 3.2. IMPORTing Symbols**:

```
Note that when symbols from "enterprise-specific" information modules
are referenced  (e.g., a descriptor), there is the possibility of
collision.  As such, if different objects with the same descriptor
are IMPORTed, then this ambiguity is resolved by prefixing the
descriptor with the name of the information module and a dot ("."),
i.e.,

    "module.descriptor"

(All descriptors must be unique within any information module.)

Of course, this notation can be used to refer to objects even when
there is no collision when IMPORTing symbols.
```

Everything seems to be clear, but...
i cannot find in standard where it can be used and i cannot find any mib that using "qualified" descriptors.

It seems that no one uses it. Is in real mib "qualified" descriptors used and how it used?

Comment: As a MIB compiler vendor, I can only comment that this feature is supported.

Comment: In the thousands of MIBs that we have encountered, we have not seen this. Does not mean much, but it seems to be a rarely used feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up some test cases for my compiler product, so post them here for your reference.

`TEST1-MIB` module who defines `mytest` as `9998`.

```
TEST1-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
IMPORTS
    enterprises
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

mytest OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { enterprises 9998 }

END
```

`TEST2-MIB` module who defines `mytest` as `9999`.

```
TEST2-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
IMPORTS
    enterprises
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

mytest OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { enterprises 9999 }

END
```

Then when `TEST3-MIB` module tries to import both, we need the prefix to determine which `mytest` would be used,

```
TEST3-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
IMPORTS
    mytest
        FROM TEST1-MIB
    mytest
        FROM TEST2-MIB;

mytest1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { TEST2-MIB.mytest 9999 }

END
```